# Excel Interop Dropdownlist events

Tags: c#, excel, dropdownbox

I am able to add a dropdown list to a cell in Excel and populate it from an array like so:

```
        Range oRange = ws.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        DropDowns xlDropDowns;
        DropDown xlDropDown;
        xlDropDowns = ((DropDowns)(ws.DropDowns(Type.Missing)));
        xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)oRange.Left, (double)oRange.Top, (double)oRange.Width, (double)oRange.Height, true);

        string[] items = new string[] { "John", "Jim", "Jason", "Joe" };

        //Add items into drop down list
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            xlDropDown.AddItem(items[i], i + 1);
        }
```

But I am not able to see how a change/selectchange event can be associated to this dropdown and how it functions (does it go back to c# code or somewhere else) documentation seems limited.  There is onAction but cant find examples on how to use that. Thanks

Comment: As far as this does not seem to be a too popular topic (not too many people in a position to help you here); wouldn't you mind to explain what is exactly what you are after (why are you so interested in getting the events from Excel)? Perhaps I (or any other person) might propose you an alternative where the events will be completely managed by C#; or alternatively, an approach relying just on VBA.

Comment: I have an excel sheet that is created on the fly using the interop, I would like to double click a cell convert that cell to a dropdown that is loaded by data from db, once a value is selected  from the dropdown or paste/typed in, validate that is on the list other wise color the cell, and send a messagebox signaling that it is new. The combobox would have worked great bec of the events to it.

Comment: I am not saying that you cannot rely on Excel events from the C# app, but getting this working might be more difficult and less reliable. From what you are saying I would rely on one of the following alternatives: creating a macro and let the user interact with the Excel file directly (why relying on C# at all if all what you want to do is in Excel?); or I would set-up a starting C# window with the combobox you are taking about (populated from the DB, etc.); depending upon the actions of the user on it, the C# application would create an Excel file and perform the required changes on it.

Comment: the thing is I am pretty new to macros and excel, what I dont understand is that excel provides a dropdown that can be added to a cell thru c#, how there is no event to be associated to it dosent sound right at all. If I create a macro and select a cell can I convert the cell which is text at that point to a dropdown in the cell loaded data from the database and be able to or view the selection and manage it

Comment: Sure there is an event associated; VBA associates an event with virtually any action on the workbook. But you have to understand what you are intending to do: with Interop you are just communicating your program with Excel. Most likely, you can get the events triggered in the Excel file/macro from C# quite easily, but you want them in your application. The events in Excel and in C# are different and this is a not-too-easy situation to be transferred from one platform to the other (it is not a simple string). Take my advice or continue waiting here for help.

Comment: ok, How do I get events in Excel/macro triggered from C#

Comment: As said, I don't have experience (and will not do the research/testing to answer you); but I am under the impression that you can easily trigger them in Excel (not getting them in C#). I told this you since the start: never had this problem because of doing what I suggested; that is, relying completely on VBA (and dealing with all the events there) or relying on C# (dealing with the events in C#) and using Excel just for information storage/retrieval/displaying. The title of your question is pretty clear; if you don't want to follow my advice, just wait for an answer.

Comment: just to be clear what do you mean by relying on c#, I am new to this c# excel do you mean having the project type being a workbook and being able to use the controls in their?

Comment: No, I mean: open your VS in C# winforms, put a combobox on the form and rely on its events. The idea is: you deliver an .exe file to the user, the user double-clicks the .exe file, a window pops-up with a combobox (this combobox is populated from your DB), the user select a given item, depending upon this selection an Excel file appears with the corresponding actions (values written here and there, backcolor set to this and that). That is, the user will not be interacting with Excel directly, but with the application; Excel would show the results. Or let the user interact just with Excel (VBA)